# Modeling Keywords and Phrases in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-many

I want to make a Keywords table that stores words in a string (from a phrase with spaces) and if the user enters a phrase it adds a reference to the keyword id in a phrases table.

I think the tables should look like this:

Keyword:

```
ID | Word
-----------
1, a
2, keyword
3, phrase
```

Domain:

```
ID | Name
-----------
1, findme.org
```

Phrase:

```
Phrase_ID | Keyword_ID | Domain_ID | Word_Weight
-----------
1, 1, 1, 0
1, 2, 1, 1
1, 3, 1, 2
```

Is there a way that I can do this in rails possibly with a has_many relationship so that I could get a phrase by passing @domain.phrases returning a list of all of the phrases with the same Domain_ID, and @keyword.phrases lists all of the phrases that contain a keyword with Keyword_ID

My goal is to avoid duplicate rows in any of the tables, is this convoluted?  Could you suggest a better design that is the rails way of doing things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your describing is very similar to the concept of tags, and so you can use any of the [tagging libraries](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_tagging) already available, and/or study their structure for a solid solution.

For example, [here is the migration](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/generators/acts_as_taggable_on/migration/templates/active_record/migration.rb) for the `acts_as_taggable_on` gem, which will give you an idea of how other people have done this, including the models (and relationships between models) in the code.

These tools provide, with very little code, the ability to add `@domain.tags` to any record. Some of the libraries also let you define what you want to call the tags - so if you want to call them keywords, you can do that, and have calls like `@domain.keywords` or `@domain.phrases`, etc., like in your example.

Also, if the ultimate goal of this is to add keywords in order to aid in searching, there are great search libraries and tools that enable [full text search](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_search) (where text, titles, etc. are automatically indexed for keywords) without needing to explicitly define keywords.

Really depends on where you want to go, but those are a couple of directions for you.

Comment: What are the pros and cons to using acts_as_taggable_on over a simple has many through association as demonstrated by elhu?

On a second note. It would be nice if there was a gem that could take as input a url, then crawl that url scrapping content and parsing it into keywords for  suggestions in my app.  Are you aware of any gems or APIs that allow you to do this?  So far I've found https://github.com/apneadiving/SemExtractor#readme it uses textwise to get text from sites but their license doesn't allow you to integrate with a web crawler/spider.

Comment: I was just pointing out the similarity of what you were asking for to the concept of tags, in case what you really wanted were tags, or the functional equivalent. The pro would be not having to implement (and maintain it) yourself, and taking advantage of the work of others instead.

Answer (score 1):

As you designed your application, you would have three models, as follow:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phrases
end

class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phrases
end

class Phrase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword
  belongs_to :domain
end
```

With this setup, you can access a domain's phrases and a keyword's phrases the way you describe at the end of your question.
If you wanted to go further, and access all the Domains with a specific keyword, or all the keywords with a specific domain, you would write your classes as follow:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phrases
  has_many :domains, through: :phrases
end

class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phrases
  has_many :keywords, through: :phrases
end

class Phrase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword
  belongs_to :domain
end
```

You could then access these informations with the following:

```
@keyword.domains # All the domains matching with the keyword
@domain.keywords # All the keywords for a specific domain
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for writing out those classes.  Would @domain.phrases return a list of keywords in the order they were saved?  I am trying to keep track of the original phrase so that I can tell my application to go out and run the search phrase that was requested.

Comment: Nevermind I missed this in your post "With this setup, you can access a domain's phrases and a keyword's phrases the way you describe at the end of your question"

Comment: By default, it would sort by ascending ID, but you can easily change this behavior using scopes. There's plenty of documentation online about that. However, I'm not sure putting sentences together from a list of separately stored words is going to perform really well. I think if you have time you should dig further in some of the solutions normalocity offered in his answer.

Comment: I think I might go with acts_as_taggable_on... I'm checking now to see if it supports tags with more than one word.  I don't want to introduce hypens in place of spaces.